# Type hinting: list of str and/or list of int

Tags: python, list, pycharm, type-hinting, python-3.10

Let's say we have a simple function to print matrices. And we want to warn users that this function works only with list or tuple of lists or tuples containing only strings.

As far as I learned from [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/) and [PEP 585](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/) the one can use generics such as `list` and `tuple` for type hinting of corresponding sequences.
Also, the typing syntax with the `list` generic type requires to use it with the only one argument - the common type of all list elements.

So, I've constructed two type variables as shown below.

But, obviously I didn't fully get the idea. It hadn't raised a warning when I passed to the function the argument contained mixed list of string and list of integers. While I expected it.

Could you please explain me this behaviour.

```py
Row = list[str] | tuple[str, ...]
Matrix = tuple[Row, ...] | list[Row]

def print_matrix(matrix: Matrix, *matrices, right: bool = False) -> None:
    """Prints one or more matrices in line to the stdout."""
    # ...

test_matr1 = [['1', '0', '0'], ['0', '1', '0'], ['0', '0', '1']]
test_matr2 = [[1, 0, 0], ['0', '1', '0'], ['0', '0', '1']]
test_matr3 = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
print_matrix(test_matr1)
print_matrix(test_matr2)
print_matrix(test_matr3)
```

Here's what PyCharm shows in the tooltip for the `test_matr2`:

> `test_matr2: list[list[int] | list[str]] = [[1, 0, 0], ['0', '1', '0'], ['0', '0', '1']]`

While I expected to see the warning, same to the one I've got for `test_matr3`.

> `Expected type 'tuple[list[str] | tuple[str, ...], ...] | list[list[str] | tuple[str, ...]]', got 'list[list[int]]' instead`

Comment: You probably want a `list[list[union[int, str]]]`. https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#union-types

Comment: interesting, looks like pycharm is unable to catch the same issue if you annotate it like `matrix: list[str]` and then try to pass in a list where not all elements are strings.

Comment: @Locke note that the OP wants to type annotate list containing only strings.

Comment: @Gennadiy it seems a bug, I would open an issue in pycharm tracker, just so that they are aware.

Comment: To be clear, you are *not* getting any kind of warning or error for `print_matrix(test_matr2)`?

Comment: (Unrelated, but do you really care to restrict this to lists and tuples, instead of any sequence? `Row = Sequence[str]; Matrix = Sequence[Row]`. Even this is underspecified, as it doesn't capture the presumed requirement that each row of a matrix have the same length.)

Comment: @chepner I will wait for OP to chime in, but personally I use pycharm all the time too, so I definitely don't see any error for `test_matr2`. I think the bug or issue in this case is that pycharm seems to accept `list[str | int]` as a more strongly typed `list[str]` for example.

Comment: @chepner, I'm _not_ getting any error for `print_matrix(test_matr2)`. And yes, you're right about `Sequence` and other requirements. What I had shown here is the model example of how we deal with type annotations in different cases including this case. However, what do you propose to check if each row of a matrix have the same length?

Comment: @rv.kvetch, I thought about PyCharm bug, but decided to ask first. Thanks for getting involved with the pycharm tracker.

Comment: The most important question for me: how to deal with `list` type annotations? It seems to me there's a kind of inconsistency. I mean that strictly saying `list` can contain elements of any type. But the type annotation syntax tells us that we should use lists with elements of an only one type.

Comment: May this inconsistency cause the accepting behavior when I'm annotating only one type for `list` elements, but passing `list` with mixed types? And should we interpret it as a bug or just solve it another way?